# Using an array of ElementType gives error in Target annotation

Tags: java, annotations

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType.*;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD})
public @interface Inter1 {
}
```

I've seen in other annotations like `SuppressWarnings` and `Deprecated` that they use an array of `ElementType` enum directly without using the enum like the above. But when I try to use it in one of my custom annotations, it gives me an error. I need to give it as ElementType.TYPE or ElementType.FIELD for it to work. What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to use that annotation this way:

import **static** java.lang.annotation.ElementType.*;

otherwise, this way:

@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})

Comment: Yes thats right! I missed the static part of it in the doc! Thanks :)